# How to sum all elements of queue in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
val queue:Queue = LinkedList(arrayListOf(353,343,5343,3434))
```

how to add these element without using loop in efficient way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kotlin's Aggregator functions Reduce and Fold for this purpose.

```
val sum: Int = queue.fold(0, { acc, next -> acc + next }) //0 is initail value of sum.
```

learn more about the Aggregate function here in this link [Aggregate Operations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-aggregate.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = 0;
while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
  var n = queue.remove();
  sum += n;
}
```

#### Edit

In kotlin you can apply the function sum() in any iterable. So you can use

```
var sum = queue.sum()
```

Comment: is there any inbuilt function to do so?

Comment: i just edited my answer. I hope it works for you